# Why does the Translation from 3 Band TIFF to ECW in FME 2017 fail?

Tags: raster, fme-form

I have a number of 16bit RGB raster images which need to be converted to ECW format. The images are displayed perfectly in ArcGIS and have the following attributes.

rows and columns: 1506, 2051
No Bands: 3
Format: TIFF
Pixel depth: 16 Bit
Compression LZW

When I load the Tiff in FME 2017 and inspect it, it is rendered black with the following information:

rows and columns: 959, 250
BAND 0 (Gray 16)
BAND 1 (UINT 16)
BAND 2 (UINT16)

My translation to ecw fails due to "Unsupported band interpretation 'GRAY16'".
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Geotiff is 16bit. Support for 16bit  ECWs was introduced in v5 of the ECW SDK.

From a quick look at the [help](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/ecw/ecw.htm) docs, it seems FME only supports writing 8bit ECWs. So the software is either using the old v3 or v4 ECW SDK or hasn't implemented the 16bit capabilities of the v5 SDK.

> Any non-eight-bit source data returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

Does the raster dataset have a palette attached to it? ie the first band has a palette that ArcGIS automatically resolves into values, but FME doesn't.

Try a RasterPaletteResolver transformer before the writer in FME. I hope that would resolve the palette into values that actually make sense for the RGB16 data type.

Edit: You may also need to use the RasterSelector transformer before the RasterPaletteResolver, in order to select which bands/palettes to resolve. Probably set to 0 0 (Band 0 Palette 0)